# Callback for Android device from REST Api

Tags: android, rest, spring-boot

I have the following architecture:

There is my backend (spring boot), with can receive data from my client (android device) over a REST api and it also provide data over the REST api.

The data which are provided, change from time to time, without a dependency from the data the client send.

Is it now possible in android to write a callback for the data which the backend provided?

You could do it with a button, but I want to get the new data automatically when ever they change. How would you do it, with a timer/interval?

For example I know Firebase (from Google), where you can do something like this, there you can define a callback and get the new data when ever they change...something like this is what I want.

Comment: you can use firebase notifcations to notify your app to get the new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical PUSH scenario, in which your app must be notified when data changes in server side.There are different approaches:

- Polling (implementing a service or alarm manager, there is a good example in this post [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example))
- FCM (which is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand), that  provides both the server and device components you need to make this messaging system work. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

I would recommend you to use FCM  to implement this scenario, without degrading performance or wasting battery life by polling the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably [do it with WebSockets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyJ4fORkHfA) but there isn't an out-of-the-box solution like with Firebase, no.